# $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to do this limit $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$$  and I cant, I will be pleased if someone give me a hint to do it.

Comment: hint : multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n(n+1-n)}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1n}+1}\\&=\frac{1}{1+1}\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you so much  for your help.

Comment: @ArisSoria If this answer was helpful, consider accepting it, by clicking $\checkmark$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
hence the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.